# Css Width fit contents

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a html page like the example in the js fiddle.
I want to make each element set the width automatically to fit the child automatically.
Is there anyway to do this without upsetting the whole page?

**html**

```
</fieldset>
<div id = 'buttons'>
  <button onclick="$('span.hidden_select').toggle(1000);">Test</button>
   <span class="hidden_select">
    <form method="post" action="/pcr_process_batch/reassign_batch">
    Choose Person :
      <select id="person" name="person">
        <option value="1249">Person 1</option>
        <option value="307">Person 2</option>    
        <option value="708">Person 3</option>
        <option value="1331">Person 4</option>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="commit">
     </form>
   </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset{
padding: 2px;
background-color:#5CE68A; 
margin-top: 20px;
float:left;
width:50%;
 }

  div#buttons{
border:1px solid black;
width:inherit;
max-height:inherit;
 }

 span.hidden_select{
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:0;
max-width:inherit;
display:none;
 }

 span.hidden_select form{
width:auto;
overflow:visible;
    border:1px solid black;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/striderinc/6G72y/6/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6G72y/1/?

Comment: how to choose comment as right answer

Comment: @j08691 He wants to stretch the stuff or he wants to limit the wrapper?

Comment: @Stacked-for-life he will answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `float:left` on the `div`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6G72y/1/)**

```
div#buttons {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:inherit;
    max-height:inherit;
    float:left;
}
```

Note that depending on your complete code, you may need to clear the float on the HTML that comes after this by applying `clear:left`.

Comment: I just realized I have a block to the left of this form and I have set the margin of the div#buttons element and when I do float left the page just looks wierd

Answer (score 0):

just apply position absolute to you span {hidden_select}

```
   span.hidden_select
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:0;
    max-width:inherit;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    /*added this to make it look in a same line*/
    top:-3px;
}
```

[here is fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/sandesh_mahajan/PK2M9/)